# sql delete not working with à

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to delete a row in a database, but for some reason it is not working.

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> 
WHERE MAPPING_ID = '66' 
  AND FIELD_VALUE = 'Sanità' 
  AND PARENT_VALUE = 'ITA';
```

Result: `66 Sanità  ITA`

```
DELETE FROM <tablename> 
WHERE MAPPING_ID = '66' 
  AND FIELD_VALUE = 'Sanità' 
  AND PARENT_VALUE = 'ITA';
```

Result: `0 rows deleted.`

I am guessing it is due to the à. I already have `SET DEFINE OFF` , but still no go.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have any primary key attached to it?

Comment: Running the script through cmd
No primary key, just those 3 columns

Comment: @user2110655 what database you are using? Oracle DB, MySQL, SQL Server? please see my answer.

Comment: @user2110655, kindly can show us the column type for `FIELD_VALUE`?

Comment: Do you enter both statements in SQL*plus directly, or do you run one in  SQL*plus and the other one from a `.sql` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM <tablename> 
WHERE MAPPING_ID = '66' 
  AND FIELD_VALUE = N'Sanità' 
  AND PARENT_VALUE = 'ITA';
```

try this N use for match nvarchar value(Unicode)

hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Sudhir.
It looks like it is working for me. Will send it n to our DBA team and see if it works for them. Thanks

Comment: So you need an N-literal when DELETE, but not when SELECT?!?

Answer (score 0):

The query you try to access is wrong the syntax should be:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE conditions;
```

If you want to specify the database name, use this

```
DELETE FROM schema.table
WHERE conditions;
```

Comment: I have the schema and table name in but for security reasons I could not show this.

Comment: I had more scripts and all the others worked fine. It is just this one with 'Sanità' that fails. Thats why I think it is due to the accent on the a.

Comment: The database is Oracle

Comment: @user2110655 try to check the character set for this: `select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET%';`

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
DELETE FROM [dbo.youtablename]
WHERE MAPPING_ID = '66' 
AND FIELD_VALUE = 'Sanità'
AND PARENT_VALUE = 'ITA';
```

**Or else set the MAPPING_ID as the primary key of the table and use:**

```
DELETE FROM [dbo.youtablename]
WHERE MAPPING_ID = '66'
```

Comment: `[dbo.yourtablename]` is invalid Oracle syntax.